# Exception on list.remove() even numbers

Tags: c#

I have a list of numbers and I’d like to remove all the even ones. I think my code is right:

```
System.Collections.Generic.List<int> list = ...
foreach (int i in list)
{
  if (i % 2 == 0)
    list.Remove(i);
}
```

but when I run it I get an exception. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: That makes more sense to me. Thanks for the replies guys. And thank you Brandon for formatting the post. It's my first time posting here. I'll learn on the go.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't modify a collection in a `foreach` loop, that being said,
you can't remove an item from a `list` that you're iterating over in a `foreach` loop.

Instead of the `foreach` loop, just use this single line of code:

```
list.RemoveAll(i => i % 2 == 0);
```

Comment: More generally, you can't modify a collection in a `foreach` loop.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot modify the collection during a `foreach` loop. A `foreach` loop uses an enumerator to loop through the collection, and when the collection is modified this is what happens to the enumerator:

> An enumerator remains valid as long as the collection remains
>   unchanged. If changes are made to the collection, such as adding,
>   modifying, or deleting elements, the enumerator is irrecoverably
>   invalidated and its behavior is undefined.

You can use a regular `for` loop.

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
{
    int n = list[i];
    if (n % 2 == 0)
    {
        list.RemoveAt(i--);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `foreach` uses an `IEnumerator` under the covers, when an element in your list is removed, it leaves the enumerator in a potentially inconsistent state. The 'safest' thing for it to do is throw an exception.

To work around this, make a local copy of your collection first:

```
var local = new List<int>(list);
foreach (int i in local) { if (i % 2 == 0) list.Remove(i); }
```

Comment: @user1100941 no problem, enjoy SO!

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this instead.  (It creates a new list of just the even numbers rather than removing the odds from the existing list, so it depends on what you're looking to do.)

```
var numbers = Enumerable.Range(1, 100);
var evens = numbers.Where(n => n % 2 == 1);
```

Comment: You'd want odds (n % 2 == 1) in this case since he's keeping the odds.

Answer (score 1):

If you're removing from a list of anything (or even an array) you should iterate backward through it as removing an item shifts all items after it down by one position. Iterating forward will cause you to skip over the next item each time.

Which exception did you get? Sometimes foreach will lock an item to where it can't be edited when it's used in the foreach. Instead, use for (and go backwards!)

```
for(int i = list.Length - 1 ; i > -1 ; i--)
```

Answer (score 1):

to follow @Chris Filstow's method....

this will take your list, and replace it with a new one where the elements meet your criteria:

```
System.Collections.Generic.List<int> list = ...
list = list.Where( n=> n % 2 == 0 ).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

All your getting out of the `foreach` loop is `readonly` if you try to change the items in the list it explains why you get an exception. 
This article right [here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/foreach) explains why.
You could alway switch to a `for` loop.

```
  for  (int i = 1 ; i < list.lenght; i++)
  {
    if (i % 2 == 0)
    list.Remove(i);

  }
```

Comment: You are checking if the index is even, not the element in the list. this is not what asked in the question